# How to add a new row to the android list view without reloading the entire list?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a Android ListView with Textview, Edit texts and spinners, list is created based on datas from database.The task is that when the user presses the add button the new row should be created without reloading the entire datas (rows) in list . Can any suggest me a best approach to do this task?

Comment: the best approach is: you cannot do that

Comment: Is there any alternate approach to do that?

Comment: whats wrong with reloading the adapter?

Comment: I am having a list with person name loaded from the database . The row contains the edit text, with that the user type in the person age. If the person wishes to add a new person name then he clicks on the add button. In that case the datas typed in the previous edit text are refreshed. I don't need this to be happened. The datas should not be changed and I like to save all the datas(including new data added) to the database at once.

Comment: update your db whenever data is added/changed/deleted, that way you avoid situations like yours

Answer (score 0):

hi refer this sample program you should get solution

`EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
list.add(edit.getText().toString());
edit.setText("");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-items-to-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

for show new rows without create new Adapter...